# Dell Latitude 5590 SD Card reader is not recognized

Tags: linux, debian, realtek

I have a DELL Latitude 5590 Notebook with Debian 9 and kernel version 4.20.0 installed. Unfortunately the onboard sd card reader does not work.
The reader is following model:

> Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS525A PCI Express Card Reader
>   Cardreader

Output of `lspci -v`

```
01:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS525A PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell RTS525A PCI Express Card Reader
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 127
    Memory at ef100000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: [80] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [90] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [b0] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [148] Device Serial Number 00-00-00-01-00-4c-e0-00
    Capabilities: [158] Latency Tolerance Reporting
    Capabilities: [160] L1 PM Substates
    Kernel driver in use: rtsx_pci
    Kernel modules: rtsx_pci
```

According to https://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/MISC_RTSX_PCI.html the needed driver is `rtsx_pci`.

If I check now with modprobe nothing happens:

```
root@sandbox:/dev# modprobe rtsx_pci
root@sandbox:/dev# 

root@sandbox:/# ls /lib/modules/4.20.0/kernel/drivers/misc/cardreader/
rtsx_pci.ko  rtsx_usb.ko
root@sandbox:/#
```

Heres the `dmesg` output: https://pastebin.com/raw/HQAX45b4

Unfortunately this is where I come to an end with my knowledge; how can I get that to work?

Comment: Did you read this bit: `found in Linux kernels: 3.10–3.19, 4.0–4.15`? Have you tried kernel 4.15?

Comment: Sorry, I added the wrong Link, fixed it now. However it is the same module `rtsx_pci`. Also as far as I remember, I installed Debian originally with a 4.9.xx Kernel version, it was not working back then either..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution now: i recently updated to kernel version 5.0.6 and enabled following settings within `make menuconfig`

```
> Device Drivers > MMC/SD/SDIO card support > Realtek PCI-E SD/MMC Card Interface Driver [M]
> Device Drivers > MMC/SD/SDIO card support > Realtek USB SD/MMC Card Interface Driver [M]
```

Answer (score 1):

I have installed Ubuntu 19.04 on a Dell Latitude E7450 which has an SD Card reader that is built into the laptop.

The ONLY way I could get a newer SD card to work on this setup, was to use an external USB adapter (USB to SD).

The built in SD Card reader but does NOT work with newer/faster SD cards. See below.

So, what I did discover is that the 32 Gig SDHC cards DID WORK, on the builtin SD Card reader, on the Dell Latitude E7450 (and some other laptops (With Ubuntu)).

NOTE: ONLY the SD-HC (32 Gig) SD Cards worked with the builtin SD Card reader, in my setup.

Basically,

- the SDHC comes in only 2 to 32 Gig and that DID WORK, without rebuilding the linux kernel.
- the SDXC or SDUC (both faster than SDHC and more memory capacity than 32 Gig) do NOT work, without tweaks.
- Meaning, 64 Gig, and greater MAY NOT work without some digging, tweaks, and/or fix(es).

For the SD-Card designations, see the following wikipedia page:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SD_card#Speed_class_rating

I will repeat, that I have NOT got the SD-Cards (this which have the SD-XC or SD-UC designations) to work with my setup.

To mitigate this issue, I just went to Walmart and bought more than one of the SD-HC (32 Gig SD cards).

Look for SDHC (10 with a circle).

And that works for me, for now.

Admittedly, this is not the most desirable solution, this is only a way to mitigate the issue, for now, until a fix is available.

Thanks!

Francis

Answer (score 0):

## You're using an unsupported kernel version.

Actually, I have no idea how you installed kernel 4.19.7 at all. Whoever compiled it probably forgot or decided not to include the `rtsx_pci` driver.

The latest kernel available in `stretch` (Debian 9) is `4.18.0-0.bpo.3` (from `stretch-backports`). If you install this kernel version, you should be able to load the rtsx_pci module.

Source:
If you look at a [list of files available in this package](https://packages.debian.org/stretch-backports/amd64/linux-image-4.18.0-0.bpo.3-amd64/filelist), you can see that it contains the line

```
/lib/modules/4.18.0-0.bpo.3-amd64/kernel/drivers/misc/cardreader/rtsx_pci.ko
```

Comment: I installed the 4.19.7 Kernel myself, but you're right - I forgot to add the `rtsx_pci` driver. Okay, in the case I would need to "extract" the source code for the driver, compile it and insert it with `insmod` right?

Comment: I updated now to Kernel version 4.20.0 and enabled `rtsx_pci `& `rtsx_usb` in `make menuconfig`. However it still does not work though. Added the information in the OP.